# share dropdown menu like stackoverflow share menu

Tags: jquery, css

How can I do share menu like stackoverflow share menu? I have a menu table but how can do show when click to share text.

[image]

I am trying like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#share').live('click', function(){
var $eid = $(this).attr('eid');  
var $url = 'share.php?eid=' + $eid;
$('#share_load'+$eid).load($url);       
});
</script>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="share" eid="12345">share</a>

<table id="share_load12345">
<tr><td>facebook:</td></tr>
<tr><td>twitter:</td></tr>
<tr><td>url:<input type="text" value="http://www.domain.com?eid=12345"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you where almost there:

1. you have to hide the table, cause you only want to show it on click: (css-> `display:none;`)
2. show it with jQuerys slideToggle().

http://jsfiddle.net/L7CpT/

```
$('#share').on('click', function(){
    var $eid = $(this).attr('eid');  
    var $url = 'share.php?eid=' + $eid;
    $('#share_load'+$eid).attr('val',$url);
    $('#share_load'+$eid).slideToggle();
});
```

I would recommend to better use `classe`s instead of `id`s. You can use them with $(this). in jQuery to know where the click happend and which table to show.

Comment: thanks for answer. code working well. 3 records coming in loop but second and third share not opening when clicked. what is problem?

Comment: if possible can you write a example for using classes instead of ids.

Comment: @webmaster http://jsfiddle.net/L7CpT/1/ also check the value part, not sure if that worked before but now it does!

Comment: how can select input text on focus and how can table style to display:none; again with close button?